# Why is the hotkey I added with the keyboard module not working?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am trying to add a hotkey with the keyboard module that will call a function with different arguments depending on the hotkey used. To do this Iam using the python3 keyboard module.

I am looking at the documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

I want my program to always be in something like a while True loop waiting for different hotkeys.

```
import keyboard

def hotkey_print(word):
    print(word)


keyboard.add_hotkey('page up, page down', lambda: hotkey_print('did it work?'))

while True:
    pass
```

I expect it to just wait and for it to print "did it work?" every time i press the up or down key but nothing happens when i use the hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

According to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) one of the limitations of the keyboard library is that it should be run as root:

```
To avoid depending on X, the Linux parts reads raw device files (/dev/input/input*) but this requries root.
```

So you can either use `su -` and become root, and run the python file again, or you can use another library (if any).

EDIT:
use the following line instead of your infinite loop:

```
# Block forever, like `while True`.
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: running it is no problem. I use sudo /home/.../python3 myscript.py and it runs. but the hotkeys just don't work at all and i stay in the while Loop forever with nothing happening.

Comment: remove the while loop and add the following line:
```keyboard.wait()```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was getting bored of it...
Just use pynput.
There are many different approaches to adding hotkeys with this module, but I just used this code I wrote:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def startHotkeys():
    if not "keysPressed" in globals():
        globals()["keysPressed"] = list()
    Thread(target=lambda: keyboard.Listener(on_press = recieveHotkey, on_release = removeHotkey).start()).start()

def recieveHotkey(inputKey):
    if not inputKey in globals()["keysPressed"]:
        globals()["keysPressed"].append(inputKey)

def removeHotkey(inputKey):
    while inputKey in globals()["keysPressed"]:
        globals()["keysPressed"].remove(inputKey)

def hotkey(key, toRun):
    Thread(target=lambda:startHotkey(key, toRun)).start()

def startHotkey(keys, toRun):
    if not "keysPressed" in globals():
        globals()["keysPressed"] = list()
    while True:
        isPressed = len(globals()["keysPressed"]) > 0 #useful hack
        if not isinstance(keys, list):
            keys = [keys]
        for i in keys:
            if not i in globals()["keysPressed"]:
                isPressed = False
                break
        if isPressed:
            runCodeObj(toRun)
        sleep(0.05)

def runCodeObj(code):
    if isinstance(code, list):
        for i in code:
            if i:
                i()
    else:
        if code:
            code()
```

call `hotkey([keyboard.KeyCode(char="a"), keyboard.Key.Enter], lambda:print("you pressed enter and a at the same time"))`
It will never stop (unless an error occurs)

```
hotkey(keyboard.Key.ctrl, exit)
```

And stuff like that...
You need to call startHotkeys() when your program begins.